# Why is “group by” so much slower than my custom CombineFn or asList()?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Mistakenly, many months ago, I used the following logic to essentially implement the same functionality as the PCollectionView's asList() method:

1. I assigned a dummy key of “000” to every element in my collection
2. I then did a groupBy on this dummy key so that I would essentially get a list of all my elements in a single array list

The above logic worked fine when I only had about 200 elements in my collection. When I ran it on 5000 elements, it ran for hours until I finally killed it. Then, I created a custom “CombineFn” in which I essentially put all the elements into my own local hash table. That worked, and even on my 5000 element situation, it ran within about a minute or  less. Similarly, I later learned that I could use the asList() method, and that too ran in less than a minute. However, what concerns me – and what I don't understand – is why the group by took so long to run (even with only 200 elements it would take  more than a few seconds) and with 5000 it ran for hours without seeming to accomplish anything.

I took a look at the group by code, and it seems to be doing a lot off steps I don't quite understand… Is it somehow related to the fact that the group by statement is attempting to run things across a cluster? Or is it may be related to using an efficient coder? Or am I missing something else? The reason I ask is that there are certain situations in which I'm forced to use a group by statement, because the data set is way too large to fit in any single computer's RAM. However, I am concerned that I'm not understanding how to properly use a group by statement, since it seems to be so slow…

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that could be contributing to the slow performance.  First, if you are using SerializableCoder, that is quite slow, and [AvroCoder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) will likely work better for you.  Second, if you are iterating through the Iterable in your ParDo after the GBK, if you have enough elements you will exceed the cache and end up fetching the same data many times.  If you need to do that, explicitly putting the data in a container will help.  Both the CombineFn and asList approaches do this for you.